# How could I rewrite this pgplsql function in standard sql?

Tags: function, postgresql, full-text-search, heroku, plpgsql

I'm developing an app using Heroku but they don't have the plpgsql language loaded for Postgres which is causing an issue when trying to run the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION profiles_search_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  begin
    new.search_vector :=
      setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.display_name,'')), 'A') ||
      setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.about,'')), 'B') ||
      setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.music_education,'')), 'D') ||
      setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.other_experience,'')), 'D') ||
      setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.favourite_artists,'')), 'D');
    return new;
  end
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How could I rewrite this using standard SQL rather than plpgsql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [**docs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/triggers.html):

> It is not currently possible to write a trigger function in the plain SQL function language.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that. Thanks. I've not seen any reference in the docs showing triggers that don't use a trigger function so I'm guessing I'll have to resort to treating all columns equally

Comment: @Kevin: you can create an index on expression without materializing it, however, you will have to retype the expression in the queries verbatim: `CREATE INDEX ix_profiles_search ON profiles USING  GIST((setweight(…) || … || setweight(…)))`